# How to avoid DETACHED object or uninitialized Hibernate proxy when using Spring Data JPA?

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa

I'm using `Spring Data JPA` and have a problem with objects that are DETACHED. I would like to know how to solve this problem.

I'm working with 2 objects : `Request` and `Event`.
A Request has a lifecycle and is processed many times all along its life time.
Each time a `Request` is processed, an `Event` is generated and stored in a table. Thus an `Event` has a reference on a `Request` and a cardinality `ManyToOne`

Request : --------------------------------------------------------------->

Event   : ----|-----------|-------------|------------|------------------->

Here isa piece of the `Event class` :

```
public class Event implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    @Getter @Setter
    private long id;
    @ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinColumn(name = "REQUESTID")
    @Getter @Setter
    private Request request;
    ...
```

A `Request` looks like this :

```
public class Request implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    @Getter @Setter
    private long id;
    @Column(name = "AMOUNT")
    @Getter @Setter
    private BigInteger amount;

}
```

Here is the SQL representation of the relationship :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS REACTIVEENGINE.EVENT (
    id int AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL ,
    requestId int NOT NULL ,
    domain varchar(50) NOT NULL ,
    step varchar(150) NOT NULL ,
    result varchar(20) NOT NULL ,
    timelog timestamp(3) NOT NULL ,
    alertId int NULL ,
    primary key (id),
    CONSTRAINT FK_EVENT_REQUEST_ID foreign key (requestId) references REQUEST (id) ON DELETE CASCADE ,
    CONSTRAINT FK_EVENT_ALERT_ID foreign key (alertId) references ALERT (id) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=UTF8MB4;
```

I encounter the problem when I want to process the `Request`. Here is a piece of the method :

```
   executorService.scheduleAtFixedRate( () -> {

        Flux<Event> eventFlux = getEventFlux();
        eventFlux.subscribe( event -> {
            Request request = requestDao.getOne(event.getRequest().getId());
            Event fundingEvent = Event.builder()
                    .domain(Domain.FUNDING)
                    .step(FundingStep.FUNDABILITY_CHECK.name())
                    .request(request)
                    .result(Event.Status.SUCCESS)
                    .timelog(LocalDateTime.now())
                    .build();
            eventDao.save(fundingEvent);
        });

    }, 0, 30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

1. My method receives an Event containing the Request.
2. My method process the Request.
3. Finally, my method creates a new Event and passes it the Request as argument for further processing by other methods downstream.

At that point, once the `Event` is created, I have to save it in the database, thus using pre-build CRUD operations of Spring's `JpaRepository` :

```
public interface IEventDao extends JpaRepository<Event, Long> {}
```

The problem is that the Request is now DETACHED :

```
reactor.core.Exceptions$ErrorCallbackNotImplemented: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: uninitialized proxy passed to persist(); nested exception is org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: uninitialized proxy passed to persist()
Caused by: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: uninitialized proxy passed to persist(); nested exception is org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: uninitialized proxy passed to persist()
```

I've tried many solutions, adding `Cascade.ALL` to Event entity.
I've also tried to add `@PersistenceContext` to my class so that I could refresh / merge the request object before injecting it in the Event object (but it doesn't work, as persistence context remains null).

What solutions could you suggest ?

Thanks by advance.

Answer (score 2):

What was your intention behind using `getOne`? Was it to associate the event with `Request`, without loading the `Request` from the DB?

If so, this will not work without a transaction. You're getting the exception because `getOne` returns a proxy, and since there is no surrounding persistence context, the proxy becomes immediately 'detached', with no way of initializing it (because the context within which it was created no longer exists).

The solution is, to simply use the original `event.getRequest()` or, if you insist on 'refreshing' the `Request` state for some strange reason - to use `findById` instead of `getOne`.

Another solution (assuming you're using the default provider for JPA, i.e. Hibernate) would be to remove `CascadeType.ALL` from `Event.request` (as it makes no sense for `@ManyToOne` anyway - you can swap it out for some subset of cascade options but **excluding** `MERGE` and `DELETE`), and simply using `new Request(event.getRequest().getId())`. For this scenario, the original `event.getRequest()` will work just as well, though.

Answer (score 0):

thanx for your time and help.

The '`getOne(...)`' is *Spring Data JPA*'s way to name the '`findById(id)`' method. At the beginning there was no call to `requestDao.getOne(event.getRequest().getId());`

There was just a `Request` object inside the previous `Event` object and I just wanted to pass it from previous to following one. `Detached` object problem arised at the moment I just wanted to use the same `Request` object taken from `Event A` to be injected in `Event B`.

That's why I tested to get a "fresh" `Request` from the database, but the problem of "`Detached`" has just been replaced by the problem of "`Proxy`" with no more persistence context. The `@Transactional` annotation I tried after did not solve the problem too.

In fact you were right about the `Cascade`, that was completely useless and non-sense in my situation. I thought it could help me save some time and lines of code to avoid *N* calls to the `save` method, one per object. I wanted to do it all in the same movement and that's why I used the `Cascade` tool.

I'm not clear with the notion of "`Proxy`" in the Hibernate context but I understand that the '`requestDao.getOne(...)`' method was not enough to create a durable persistence context that would be latter used by the `Event`'s dao layer.

I also understand that the use of the `Cascade` principle was definitely not adapted in my situation. The `Cascade.PERSIST` is OK when both objects have to be created at the same time. But in my case, the `Request` object was already created, just re-used by a new `Event` object. But Hibernate is not able to persist one and just merge/update the other one.

Finally I suppressed the `Cascade` keyword and saved each object at a time. It is simple and working.